# start and stop button, need to disable and hide then reenable and visible

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

Okay i know this has been a question asked b4, but since it should be easy to answer i would like to get a better answer. I have a start and a stop button on a timer. I want the play button to be disabled while the clock is running and enabled when the clock is stopped, visa versa, but also i would like it to be hidden when its disabled, so could some show me the code to disable and hide a button that has been recently pressed and then reenabled and visible when the other one is pressed.

Comment: Link up an `IBAction` in IB to the button for a press event. Then just use some bools and the `hidden` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have IBOutlets to the buttons and then access them directly. Don't forget to link them on Xcode

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *startButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *stopButton;
```

On the action linked to the tap of play button:

```
[self->stopButton setEnabled:YES];
[self->stopButton setHidden:NO];

[self->startButton setHidden:YES];
[self->startButton setEnabled:NO];
```

Then, when you tap the stop button:

```
[self->stopButton setEnabled:NO];
[self->stopButton setHidden:YES];

[self->startButton setHidden:NO];
[self->startButton setEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: in this simple case i think @property isn't requiered.

Comment: very good but yes @property scores it up and it should be self->startButton not . but ->, please edit it that way because that is how it worked for me.

Comment: @comradsky I edited the answer to use arrows as you said it worked. If the answer worked for you please accept it.

Comment: @TomaszSzulc if you create the Outlet by dragging from storyboard to .m file, it automatically creates a property.

Answer (score 0):

in XIB you must create buttons and connect to ViewController.h

in `interface` you must have

```
IBOutlet UIButton *btn1;
IBOutlet UIButton *btn2;

-(IBAction)b1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)b2:(id)sender;
```

in `implementation` you must write somthing like this:

in `viewDidLoad`

```
btn1.enabled = no;


-(IBAction)b1 {
    btn1.enabled = no;
    btn1.hidden = yes;

    btn2.enabled = yes;
    btn2.hidden = no;
}

 -(IBAction)b2 {
    btn2.enabled = no;
    btn2.hidden = yes;

    btn1.enabled = yes;
    btn1.hidden = no;
}
```

i think, `hidden = yes` it's  sufficient